# How to tell memory usage of SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, direct2d, sharpdx

I am loading a bunch of images as bitmaps (of the type SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap), and want to stop loading more, when the images take up a certain amount of memory (4gb in my case).
The function i have, to tell the memory used, does width * height * 4 (since it is rgba).
When using that method for System.Drawing.Bitmap, and checking with the task manager, it uses a bit more than 4gb, which is expected, since the bitmaps aren't the only thing using memory.
However, when using SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap, it only uses up 350mb total.
Since the images still display correctly, i can conclude that no data is lost, which must mean that it is compressed.
However i have no idea how to tell how much memory it uses in such a case.
While it is not a critical problem, since it uses less memory than expected, i would like to make use of that fact.

So, does anyone know how to tell, how much memory a SharpDX.Direct2D1.Bitmap uses?

EDIT: turns out, it is loaded to gpu memory. I'd mark this as solved, but idk how. thanks @SimonMourier

Comment: Direct2D bitmaps are loaded by the GPU, not the CPU like GDI/GDI+ bitmaps (and this is not specific to SharpDX). Have you checked GPU's memory?

Comment: Images on a gpu may have mipmaps and/or use texture compression, compression typically reduces the size by a fixed factor of 4. I have no idea if SharpDX uses this automatically or if it just stores the image bytes. The size calculation should specifically be `stride * height`, even it will likely result in the same value. Also note that SharpDX has not been maintained since 2019.

Comment: @SimonMourier you are right! when cheking gpu memory i get exactly what i expected! thanks

Comment: Answer yourself if you're happy

Answer (score 0):

turns out, it is loaded to gpu memory. thanks @SimonMourier

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).